# Using daily assistance registers to know if personal is currently on the office

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to make a column in which a color/icon indicates that the person is currently on the office or he/she is out due to multiple reasons. I have the following columns in a excel sheet to register the absences:

Employee name   -   Initial date(of absence)    -  end date(of absence)  - Type of absence  - Days

Example: John  - 2/16/2018 -  2/16/2018 - sickness-    1

What I would like to know is that if there's a way to use =TODAY() formula and compare it with the list and put in a column a certain color/sign depending if the person is currently absent. For example, having a column right beside the persons name that is named status and has this characteristic.

Maybe this is not possible in excel, or I should change the method of entering data. I'm open to opinions on ways to improve this system and answering doubts about the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Already solved, including the problem mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a column with this formula `=IF(AND(TODAY()>=B2,TODAY()<=C2),-1,0)`. This will show -1 if the person is out today.

Then use conditional formatting to get your color.

Comment: Thanks! The reasoning you made is impressive!

The next step, which I forgot to mention on the question, is that the point of this is to have a separate sheet, which lists the entire employee list and reads the column that is using this formula. For example:

Employee list-     Out?
John                       -1
Kevin                       0
Mike                       -1

Is there a way to do this? What comes in my mind is a formula including IF, AND, but I'm currently in the formulation of it.